# What is an Android equivalent of IQVoiceRecorder?

Tags: java, android, audio, mobile

I'm looking to allow users to record and then cut/trim their recordings on their Android devices: I've used IQVoiceRecorder (https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQAudioRecorderController) controller on iOS but can't find something similar for Android -

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: [ffmpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)

Comment: @RRR am I missing something? It doesn't look like the ffmpeg link you shared has the gui editing etc. That's something I'd need to build?

Comment: Yes it will not provide any GUI, you need to build it by own.

Comment: :( understood. Thanks @RRR